# How to include unpublished dependencies/libraries in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I want to build a currently unpublished library and an application which uses it.

How to include an unpublished library in the executable application's `Cargo.toml` file?

From looking at the [creates documentation](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#overriding-with-local-dependencies) it looks like it's something along the line of:

```
paths = ["/path/to/uuid"]
```

How to include unpublished libraries in rust projects using filepaths, or github/gitlab repository links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paths` are set in `.cargo/config`, not in `Cargo.toml`, and are only for replacing already existing dependencies with local forks.

Unpublished crates can be referenced either by [git](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories); other crates in the same repository by [local path](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies).